# Javascript array position

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

so i have 2 arrays (server_name and server_state). 
Now i want to check the server_state array if there is a 0,1,2,3. So the possible numbers are 0,1,2 or 3. Something like

```
var server_state = [1, 0, 3, 2];
var server_name = [server1, server2, server3, server4];
```

Now i want to save the POSTITION of the number if it is 0,1,2 or 3 and save the position in a variable so that i can go into the array server_name and get the servername of the position like the number is. And these two infos (state so 0,1,2 or3 AND the server name should be saved in two other variables so i can use them later. 
Do you have any ideas about that? Maybe with a for and a if? It is known how long the array is...

Comment: Please precise your question.

Comment: Is `server_name` supposed to contain strings? It's storing variables that are not in the examples scope right now.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

If you're guaranteed that the only possible numbers in `server_state` are 0-3, you can do this:

```
var positions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < server_state.length; i++) {
  positions[server_state[i]] = i;
}
```

At the end, the array will contain the positions. (i.e. the position of `3` is `positions[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()` method on server_names and check each index of a and b in server_state array to sort by that value.

```js
var server_state = [1, 0, 3, 2];
var server_name = ['server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4'];

var sorted = server_name.sort(function(a, b) {
  return server_state[server_name.indexOf(a)] - server_state[server_name.indexOf(b)]
})

console.log(sorted)
```

You could also create one object and add each element from server_state as value and its index as key, and then add to new array by order of that object.

```js
var server_state = [1, 0, 3, 2];
var server_name = ['server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4'];

var obj = {}, result = []
server_state.forEach((e, i) => obj[i] = e)
server_name.forEach((e, i) => result[obj[i]] = e)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

While your question is not clear; here is how I understood it:

You would like the name of the server that has a state value of (0, 1, 2, or 3).

Here I look at all the server names (server_name.map) and create a new array from them, containing either the server name (if server has a state value of 0,1,2,or 3) or return null if the state value is not between 0 and 3.  You can this filter out the null values using filter()

```
 const server_names_having_valid_state = server_name.map((name, idx) => [0,1,2,3].contains(server_state[idx]) ? name : null);
 const names_without_nulls = server_names_having_valid_state.filter(x => x !== null);
```